# How should budding off be prevented on Gardenias?

Tags: plant-health, flowering, gardenias

How can budding off be stopped on a mature [Gardenia](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=gardenia&source=web&cd=1&sqi=2&ved=0CFoQFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gardenia&ei=dBZYT-mtFcTa0QG8_PiuAg&usg=AFQjCNEyQpWZ4sKwCCGz8PpCOoZ1Bo8C1A)? The plant is healthy in all other ways, but the buds always fall off before opening. What is causing this?

Comment: I've posted an answer on the most common reason I could thing of, I'll edit if these question bring anything to light.  Have you had a problem with it before or has it just reached maturity?  Is it being moved around at all by a fan/people? Is it in a particularly dry place?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things that can cause Gardenias to drop their buds prematurely.  The most common cause being a **lack of humidity**.  What is the relative humidity where it is being kept?  Gardenias are native to a very humid, tropical environment and like a lot of heat and light, but not direct sunlight.

A few other reasons I can think of:

- What is the soil pH?  Gardenias like acidic soil.
- Is the pot being moved around a lot? A lot of motion can easily cause dropping buds.
- Is there a lack of light/heat?

For humidity you can try using a humidifier to increase the humidity or a tray of pebbles in water under the pot I've heard can work.  [Here](http://www.gardeningknowhow.com/flower/gardenia-flowers-gardenia-buds-falling-off-plant.htm) are more information and references if needed.